# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: laravel

I have a form to submit add salarie, the problem here if I delete the function store in controller, it even gives me error instead of giving me error function store does not exist.

> **SalarieController.php**

```
public function store(request $request){
      Salarie::create($request->all());
      session()->flash('success','salarie add successfully');
      return redirect('salaries');
    }
```

> **web.php**

```
Route::resource('salaries', 'SalarieController');
```

> **create.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ url('salaries') }}" method="post">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3  @if($errors->get('matricule')) has-error @endif">
                      <input type="text" name="matricule" class="form-control" value="{{ old('matricule') }}" placeholder="matricule">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3  @if($errors->get('nom')) has-error @endif">
                      <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control" value="{{ old('nom') }}" placeholder="nom">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3  @if($errors->get('prenom')) has-error @endif">
                      <input type="text" name="prenom" class="form-control" value="{{ old('prenom') }}" placeholder="prenom">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3  @if($errors->get('cin')) has-error @endif">
                      <input type="text" name="cin" class="form-control" value="{{ old('cin') }}" placeholder="cin">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3 ">
                      <input type="date" name="daten" class="form-control" value="{{ old('daten') }}" placeholder="date naissance">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <select class="form-control" name="situationf">
                              <option>celebataire</option>
                              <option>marie</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <input type="text" name="nbree" class="form-control" value="{{ old('nbree') }}" placeholder="nombre d'enfant">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <input type="text" name="cnss" class="form-control" value="{{ old('cnss') }}" placeholder="matricule CNSS">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3  @if($errors->get('salairenet')) has-error @endif">
                      <input type="text" name="salairenet" class="form-control" value="{{ old('salairenet') }}" placeholder="salaire net">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3  @if($errors->get('unite')) has-error @endif">
                      <select class="form-control" name="unite">
                              <option>Heure</option>
                              <option>Jour</option>
                              <option>Mois</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <input type="text" name="hs" class="form-control" value="{{ old('hs') }}" placeholder="tarif HS">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <input type="date" name="datee" class="form-control" value="{{ old('datee') }}" placeholder="date embouche">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                     <select class="form-control" name="fonction_id">
                        <option></option>
                       @foreach($fonctions as $fonction)
                      <option value="{{ $fonction->id }}">{{ $fonction->fonction}}</option>
                       @endforeach
                     </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <input type="text" name="primer" class="form-control" value="{{ old('primer') }}" placeholder="prime rendement">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <input type="text" name="primel" class="form-control" value="{{ old('primel') }}" placeholder="prime de longement">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <input type="text" name="primet" class="form-control" value="{{ old('primet') }}" placeholder="prime de transport">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <select class="form-control" name="chantier_id">
                              <option></option>
                               @foreach($chantiers as $chantier)
                              <option value="{{ $chantier->id }}">{{ $chantier->chantier}}</option>
                               @endforeach
                      </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme btn-lg" value="submit">Ajouter</button>
                </div>
              </div>

              </form>
```

> **Salarie.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Salarie extends Model
{
    public function chantier(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Chantier');
    }
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: Can you try tweaking `public function store(request $request){` to `public function store(Request $request){`?

Comment: Could you plz add your table salaries schema ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing some options values

here

```
<select class="form-control" name="situationf">
      <option>celebataire</option> // must be <option value="celeb_value">celebataire</option> 
      <option>marie</option> // must be <option value="marie_value">celebataire</option> 
</select>
```

here also

```
<select class="form-control" name="unite">
       <option>Heure</option> // must be <option value="heure_value">Heure</option> 
       <option>Jour</option> // must be <option value="jour_value">Jour</option> 
       <option>Mois</option> // must be <option value="mois_value">Mois</option> 
</select>
```

here too

```
<select class="form-control" name="fonction_id">
      <option></option> // remove empty option or set function_id to nullable
      @foreach($fonctions as $fonction)
      <option value="{{ $fonction->id }}">{{ $fonction->fonction}}</option>
      @endforeach
</select>
```

and here

```
<select class="form-control" name="chantier_id">
        <option></option> // same as function_id
        @foreach($chantiers as $chantier)
        <option value="{{ $chantier->id }}">{{ $chantier->chantier}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```